# Data frame: get row and update it

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to select a row based on a condition and then update it in dataframe.

One solution I found is to update `df` based on condition, but I must repeat the condition, what is the better solution so that I get the desired row once and change it?

```
df.loc[condition, "top"] = 1
df.loc[condition, "pred_text1"] = 2
df.loc[condtion, "pred1_score"] = 3
```

something like:

```
row = df.loc[condition]
row["top"] = 1
row["pred_text1"] = 2
row["pred1_score"] = 3
```

Comment: What are `sents2` and `top` variables? Can you update your post with a sample of them and the dataframe, please?

Comment: @Corralien they are some new values, are they important? I changed it to 1 2, 3 in question

Comment: `df.loc[condition, ['top', 'pred_text1', 'pred_score']] = (1,2,3)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang okay if that's the shortest solution, I can go with it, however if the updated values are long statements, it's not very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the boolean mask and set it as a variable.

```
m = condition
df.loc[m, 'top'] = 1
df.loc[m, 'pred_text1'] = 2
df.loc[m, 'pred1_score'] = 3
```

but the shortest way is:

```
df.loc[condition, ['top', 'pred_text1', 'pred_score']] = [1, 2, 3]
```

**Update**

> Wasn't it possible to retrieve the index of row and then update it by that index?

```
idx = df[condition].idx
df.loc[idx, 'top'] = 1
df.loc[idx, 'pred_text1'] = 2
df.loc[idx, 'pred1_score'] = 3
```

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that it can't select a pointer to a row to update it

Comment: No because it's create a subset copy of your dataframe and the `row` variable has no reference to the original dataframe

Comment: Wasn't it possible to retrieve the index of row and then update it by that index?